# Decomposition of potassium permanganate under prolonged heating

Tags: reaction-mechanism

When we heat potassium permanganate, the equation of the decomposition of it is: 
$$\ce{2KMnO4 ->[\Delta] K2MnO4 + MnO2 + O2}$$

So  what will happen to potassium manganate ($\ce{K2MnO4}$) when we continue heating?

Comment: There are numerous mixed oxide of Mn, so I believe structures like $\ce{KMnO2}$ will be formed.

Answer (score 4):

Potassium manganate is produced by reacting manganese dioxide with potassium hydroxide and oxygen gas :

$\ce{2 MnO2 + 4 KOH + O2 → 2 K2MnO4 + 2 H2O}$

So I would suspect that the reverse process will occur when further heating. (Of course when there is no water available you might get other products, maybe potassium oxide instead of potassium hydroxide)

Comment: I expected the same, but my results are different.

Answer (score 1):

The reaction is given [here](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-6629).

$$\ce{3K2MnO4 ->[\Delta] 2K3MnO4 + MnO2 + O2}$$

> The thermal decomposition of potassium manganate to produce [potassium
>   hypomanganate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_hypomanganate), manganese(IV) oxide and oxygen. This reaction takes
>   place at a temperature of 190-500°C.

Comment: I cannot confirm this result. I tested this in reduction atmosphere by mixing the manganate with carbon (charcoal, cleaned) powder and heating to about 700C. The result is reddish brown solid, does not dissolve in or react with water. Neither manganese oxide, nor the hypomanganate look like that.